# Debian exim4 rate limits

Tags: email-server, exim, debian-wheezy, rate-limiting

I try to limit on exim4 the outgoing mails per day per domain, i found this:

```
acl_check_ratelimit:
    accept  authenticated = *
            endpass
            ratelimit     = 40 / 1d / per_rcpt / leaky / ${lc:${local_part:$authenticated_id}}
    accept
```

And its atm in my exim4.conf.template config but it dosent works, any idea?
I am using exim 4.80, Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with e-mails when the limit is reached?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one action on this rule - accept, so even if some domain will reach this limit - accept action will be applied. change rule to:

```
deny message = Sender rate exceeds SMTP limit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period
    ratelimit     = 40 / 1d / per_rcpt / leaky / ${lc:${local_part:$authenticated_id}}
```

but this will limit only authenticated users, you can read more in [exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html#SECTratelimiting)  (chapter 43 contains examples)